# Can you please tell me how to calculate the lowest and highest number in this list using python

Tags: web.py, setup.py

```
markList=[]
while True:
    mark=float(input("Enter your marks here(Click -1 to exit)"))
    if mark == -1:  break
    markList.append(mark)

markList.sort()
mid = len(markList)//2
if len(markList)%2==0:
    median=(markList[mid]+ markList[mid-1])/2
    print("Median:", median)

else:
    print("Median:" , markList[mid])     #please do not touch anything starting from this line and above, I have already found the median with this and all Im looking for it to
```

find out the lowest and highest grades, this program is asking for the user to input their grades and it telss you the highest, lowest and grade average

```
min(mark)
print("The lowest mark is", min(mark))

max(mark)
print("The highest mark is", max(mark))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We help people who help themselves and ask questions that other people are also probably pondering. We don't do your homework for you. But we might help if you show us that you've at least tried to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my answer yet?

Comment: @DavidZemens answer is good.  You should accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Python expert by any stretch but I've learned some basics.  You can refer to the documentation on the `list` object here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

`list` objects in python allow a `min()` and `max()` function.  You can call these even before you sort the list, for example:

`print min(marklist)` or `print max(marklist)`.

Since you've already sorted the list to do your median calculation, you could also just retrieve the first and last item in the list, as the lowest & highest marks, respectively:

```
print marklist[0] #prints the first/0-index position in the list
```

And likewise the maximum value, since python supports reverse-indexing of list objects:

```
print marklist[-1] #prints the last position in the list
```

I tested it with this simple code:

```
marklist=[]
marklist=[10,13,99,4,3,5,1,0,22,11,6,5,38]
print min(marklist),max(marklist)
marklist.sort()
print marklist[0],marklist[-1]
```

Comment: That was not the answer I was looking for, I wanted to just find the lowest and highest number in the list because I made a grade calculating program and I have already found out how to make it find the median.

Comment: Can you give some example if your inputs and the expected results?  This solution does show you how to return the lowest and highest values from a list. Why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: This is what comes up every time, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Liban\Com Sci\listAssign1.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(min(mark),max(mark))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
>>>

Comment: You're using the function on the wrong object. `mark` is a `float`, not a `list`. You need to use the function on the `marklist` object.

Comment: Its now saying marklist isn't defined but it already identified marklist as a list and calculated the median

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as accepted, since it provides two ways of obtaining the desired information; the errors you encountered seem to be due to your implementation, not a faulty method.